# C# dotnet MongoDB UpdateMany command using linq (abstracted db access)

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, abstraction

## My Problem

I'm using an abstracted database layer between my app and mongodb.
I need to update an entire collection (UpdateMany). Could be 2 records, could be 200 million.
For this reason, I'm having trouble executing an abstracted UpdateMany, specifically, when either the Filter, or Update expressions include more than one value or property.

I can update one field, based on a single field in the filter, but i require multiple in both.

I know I can can "find" data, convert that to a list, the iterate the list and "update" one by one (which is what all examples I've seen say to do - example below) but seriously... 200 million records!!!

## Background

My actual application **knows nothing of MongoDB**. It's using IQueryable for simple queries, and abstracted Insert, Update, Delete functions for individual entities by ID.

For queries, this works well. I retrieve an IQueryable of a collection, and use LINQ to query for some data.

```cs
public class AbstractionLayer {
    public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>(string collectionName) {
        return db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

I know, `mongoCollection.AsQueryable()` returns an `IMongoQueryable`, but the rest of the app will only ever know about the generic `IQueryable` from System.Linq.
Then, in my service (where dbAbstraction is an AbstractionLayer), I want to create a query for:

Mongo shell query: `db.Books.find({ "Publisher": "Penguin", "Year": { $gt: 1980 }})`

Which looks like this:

```cs
public MyService {
    public void DoStuff() {
        var query = dbAbstraction.GetQueryable<Book>();
        var books = query
            .Where(b => b.Publisher == "Penguin")
            .Where(b => b.Year > 1980)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Brilliant... I can create complex queries using Linq such as Where(), sorting, Take() etc.

Similarly, I can perform an "Update" by passing in an ID, and an update "Expression" using the following abstraction function:

```cs
public class AbstractionLayer {
    public bool UpdateOne<T>(string id, Expression<Func<T, object>> updateExpr, object value)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(nameof(T));
        var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(o => o.Id, id);
        var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(updateExpr, value);
        var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
        return result.IsAcknowledged && result.MatchedCount > 0;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
// Update the publisher of a single book with the given ID:
_ = dbAbstraction.UpdateOne<Book>("1234567890abcdef12345678", b => b.Publisher, "Secret Publisher");
```

## Main Question:

However, for Update Many, with a complex filter query, I can't create anything more complex than filtering by a single field, and updating a single field.

I need to do this update many via the DB, as "finding" all matching docs, converting them (`.ToList()`) to an object list then iterating them back into individual update statements could bring the system down if there's 200 million matching records in a given update.
I know Mongo can do this in the background very quickly.

I have this so far:

```cs
    public UpdateMany<T>(
        Expression<Func<T, object>> findExpression,
        object filterValue,
        Expression<Func<T, object>> updateExpression,
        object updateValue)
    {
        var collection = this.GetCollection<T>(nameof(T));
        var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(findExpression, filterValue);
        var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(updateExpression, updateValue);
        _ = collection.UpdateMany(filter, update);
    }
```

But, this will only do a simple filter (by one field and value only) and can only update a single field at a time.

```cs
UpdateMany<Book>(b => b.Publisher, "Penguin", b => b.Publisher, "Secret Publisher");
```

But, if I want to update multiple fields, or use multiple values in the find expression, I'm stuck.

How, if even possible, do I specify callbacks in a way I can filter using multiple conditions, as well as update multiple values of the matched documents?

### Example of the required "update many" in Mongo Shell

My exact updates could have many times more properties than this, but as a simple example:

e.g. Mongo shell query: `db.Books.Update({ "Publisher": "Penguin", "Year": { $gt: 1980 }}, { "Publisher": "Secret Publisher", "LastUpdatedBy": "My Username" }, { multi: true })`;

## Update

Progress so far...

My filter definition can now be defined as a single expression by changing the interface to (ignore the async differences to original question - my actual codebase if fully async):

```cs
Task<bool> UpdateAsync<TEntity>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filterExpression,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> updateExpression,
        object updateValue)
```

Calling:

```cs
await UpdateManyAsync(
    x => x.Publisher == "Penguin" && x.Year > 1980,
    x => x.Publisher,
    "Secret Publisher");
```

So, to figure out the second half...